# Help with solving : $\int_0^R \sqrt{R^2- x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

$$\int_0^R \sqrt{R^2- x^2}dx $$
$$ = \int_0^R R\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{R}\right)^2}dx $$
$$ = \int_0^{\pi/2} R\sqrt{1-\sin^2{(t)}}\cdot \cos(t) dt $$
$$ = \int_0^{\pi/2} R\cos^2(t)dt $$
$$ = \int_0^{2\pi}R\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2} $$
$$ = \frac{R}{2}\left(\sin(\pi)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{\pi \cdot R}{4} . $$

Is my solution correct? In the substitution I used: $\frac{x}{R}=\sin(t)$.

However Wolfram Mathematica does not give me a solution when I type it in, that's why I am curious to know.

EDIT: My solution is slightly incorrect, since the substitution has to be injective, and $\sin(x)$ is not injective for all $R$,... Does anybody know how to formulate it to be correct?

Comment: It should be times $R^\color{red}2$; note that this is the area in a quarter of a circle of radius $R$

Comment: $dx = R\cos(t) dt$... that's the error, but otherwise correct.

Comment: $\sin$ is injective $[0,\pi/2] \rightarrow [0, 1]$, which is all you need to worry about. Also, if you plot this, you'll see why intuitively the answer must be $\pi R^2/4$.